# Xamarin - ArchiveAll causes VisualStudio 2017 to crash

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, crash, archive

As mentioned, when I do the ArchiveAll in Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.2) on the Xamarin(4.8.0.753) project, it fails and immediately freezes & restarts the Visual Studio. I checked VS's Activity Log (AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_8a099532\ActivityLog.xml), no success. Also forums on Xamarin or general google searches - no success.
Any recommendation where I could find a useful information on this ?

Comment: update to 15.6.6 and look if this fixes it.

Comment: initially the update did not solve anything, I got a couple of restarts, but then it stopped, and its muuuch better :) thanks